# Return to Activity with correct Transition or without Shared Element Transition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, shared-element-transition

i used [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition) guide to make a simple RecyclerView (in a fragment) to Activity Shared Element Transition with multiple elements and it all worked fine up the point i am trying to get back. Althought i pass the ViewHolder as seen below sometimes the return animation ends up on different element on the RecyclerView which is really bad.

```
 public void onPetClicked(PetRecyclerViewAdapter.PetViewHolder holder, int position) {

            Intent newPostIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostDetailsActivity.class);
            newPostIntent.putExtra("TYPE", mPostType);
            newPostIntent.putExtra("POSTED_PET",  mPetList.get(position));

            Pair<View, String> area = Pair.create(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.removable), "content_area");
            Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPetImage), "petImage");
            Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle), "postTitle");
            Pair<View, String> p3 = Pair.create(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvInfo), "postDescription");
            Pair<View, String> p4 = Pair.create(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlDate), "postDate");
            Pair<View, String> p5 = Pair.create(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlLocation), "postLocation");
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), area, p1, p2, p3, p4,p5);

            getActivity().startActivity(newPostIntent, options.toBundle());
```

Not being able to fix this i decided to actually not use a return animation so in my second activity i replaced

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        supportFinishAfterTransition();
    }
```

with

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
         finish();
         overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
```

but now when i go back all shared elements are empty!

So, i am trying to figure a way, either to make the return transition work properly, meaning the "fading" effects to fade on the correct item, OR to remove the return transition all together.

Edit: On the direction of actually making it work I tried to obtain and use the View that was clicked instead of the ViewHolder but again, i got the same results. As soon as i was scrolling the recycler view and opening an item, the views would animate back to a row different than the one they started.

```
 public void onPetClicked(View view, PetRecyclerViewAdapter.PetViewHolder holder, int position) {
            mPetList.get(position);

            Intent newPostIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostDetailsActivity.class);
            newPostIntent.putExtra("TYPE", mPostType);
            newPostIntent.putExtra("POSTED_PET",  mPetList.get(position));

            Pair<View, String> area = Pair.create(view.findViewById(R.id.removable), "content_area");
            Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(view.findViewById(R.id.ivPetImage), "petImage");
            Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle), "postTitle");
            Pair<View, String> p3 = Pair.create(view.findViewById(R.id.tvInfo), "postDescription");
            Pair<View, String> p4 = Pair.create(view.findViewById(R.id.rlDate), "postDate");
            Pair<View, String> p5 = Pair.create(view.findViewById(R.id.rlLocation), "postLocation");
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), area, p1, p2, p3, p4,p5);

            getActivity().startActivity(newPostIntent, options.toBundle());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `finish()` without `super.onBackPressed()`.

I'm guessing your Activity is an AppCompatActivity? It will execute the pending Transition before finishing.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're setting the transitionName in your shared element Pairs won't work. When you return to your calling Activity, the system is looking for a unique view with those transition names, but it isn't finding it. You need to actually call `setTransitionName` on your shared Views.

You'd want to set unique transitionNames on each ViewHolder. Consider concatenating the `adapterPosition` to the View's transitionName, then pass that position as an extra to your called Activity which sets the transitionName of its Views with that position value.